# Authentication failed connecting to MongoDB running in a local docker cointainer from Spring Boot application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, spring-data-mongodb

I cannot connect to a *mongodb* instance running in a local docker container from my *spring boot* application. When the application tries to connect to the database the error below is thrown:

```
2022-04-03 22:45:57.243 ERROR 14559 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256, userName='root', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256, userName='root', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}] with root cause

com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:418) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
```

This is the docker-compose mongodb service definition:

```yaml
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - "mongo_data:/tmp/techbank/mongo"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always # fixes MongoNetworkError when mongodb is not ready when mongo-express starts
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
```

I can access the database from mongo-express client, when all services are up and running.

These are the spring data mongodb properties:

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: bankAccount
      username: root
      password: Pa$$w0rd
      authentication-database: admin
```

I also tried:

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
       uri: "mongodb://root:Pa$$w0rd@localhost:27017/bankAccount=true&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"
```

I have found similar questions on *stackoverflow*, but the suggested solutions does not work in my case.

You may find instructions to run the application locally here [techbank-build-github](https://github.com/ehayik/techbank-build/tree/mongodb-auth-issue)

If you need more details leave your comments below.

Comment: I have no clue about docker and spring, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Mark Bramnik answer I realized that I cannot authenticate to the *mongodb* container using `root:Pa$$w0rd` credentials.

I created a file named `init-mongo.js`:

```js
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "storeAdmin",
        pwd: "storeAdmin2022",
        roles: [
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "bankAccount"
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Added `./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo-js:ro` under `services:mongodb:volumes` in `the docker-compose.yml` in order to copy `init-mongo.js` to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` as a read only file.

`/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` is a folder that is already created inside the *mongodb* container used for initiating the database.

Then updated the spring data *mongodb* properties accordingly:

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: bankAccount
      username: storeAdmin
      password: storeAdmin2022
```

Now it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a network issue rather than authentication?

Spring boot application specifies a "localhost" here, so I assume it doesn't run with docker-compose...

I suggest trying the following:

1. Try to connect with some kind of client (robomongo, mongod whatever) and make sure it's accessible at all
2. Try to bind mongo itself to all the interfaces by adding an option of `--bind_ip_all` as the [official mongo documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/) suggests

Comment: yes, the spring app is not running within docker. I could confirm the mongodb image is not accessible from other clients using `root:Pa$$w0rd` credentials even adding `--bind_ip_all`,.I had tried with a newly created user and it  worked, thanks for the hint!!!