# A Spring Boot Docker container won't connect with its MongoDB Docker container database

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build and create a connection between two Docker containers using a `docker-compose.yml` file as well as my Spring Boot app's `application.yml` file.  One container is for my Spring Boot app and the other is for its MongoDB database.

As it stands, this is the error I receive when I run `docker build spring-app .` followed by `docker compose up` (in the directory of the docker-compose file):

`spring | 2023-11-28T00:49:54.130Z INFO 1 --- [product-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server database:27017`

I've tried removing the authentication requirement for the database, and this allows the app to connect to the database.  I no longer get this error, and it connects properly.

I've tried removing the ports, assigning a Docker network to both containers, and explicitly assigning the authentication-database.  For each of these, I still receive the same "Exception in monitory thread" error.

I've also tried the option of using a mongo-init.js file, like is used in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71729732/authentication-failed-connecting-to-mongodb-running-in-a-local-docker-cointainer) question, but this resulted in a directory already exists error for me.

```
networks:
  spring-docker-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  product-db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "product-db"
    networks:
      - spring-docker-network
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    hostname: product-db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin_username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin_password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: product-db

  spring-app:
    depends_on:
      - product-db
    image: spring-app
    container_name: "spring-app"
    restart: no
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - spring-docker-network
    links:
      - product-db

volumes:
  data: {}
```

Here is my `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: product-db
      host: product-db
      port: 27017
      auto-index-creation: true
      username: admin_username
      password: admin_password
      authentication-database: admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using application.yml, you need to configure your connection to the database in a config Java class where you configure everything in regards to MongoDB.

Define your connection string in your instantiation of MongoClient, MongoTemplate, and MongoDatabase.